# Definition of $Spin^c$ structure

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

The $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$-structure is well-known to be defined as the principal $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$-bundle that covers the oriented orthonormal frame bundle of an oreinted Riemannian manifold.

I've also read definition saying that the $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$-structure is a circle bundle over the total space of oriented orthonormal frame bundle, which is also equipped with a Principal $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$-bundle structure.

My question is, defining this way, how could we have the fiber is $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$? Shouldn't the fiber just be $SO(n)\times U(1)$, which is clearly not $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$ since we have the identification that $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}/\mathbb{Z}_2 \simeq SO(n) \times U(1)$ ?

Any comment is appreciated. I've attached the screenshot below for the exact sentence I encountered in the text. [image]

Comment: No, there is no reason why the fibre must be the product, just as a fibre bundle is not necessarily a product.  The compatibility is there to guarantee, among other things, that we do get fibres $\operatorname{Spin}^c(4)$ over $M$ instead of any fibre $F$ that fits inside a fibre bundle $U(1)\to F\to SO(4)$.

Comment: @user10354138 I know we don't naturally have the fiber is a product, but if we take the local trivialization of both bundle, don't we then have the fiber as product? I'm confused.

Comment: There is no reason why you can trivialise over the entire SO(4) fibre.  Local trivialization over $\mathfrak{F}$ just means you just have every point $x$ of the SO(4) fibre over some point $p\in M$ you can find neighbourhood corresponding to both in SO(4) and in the base $M$ so you get a trivial circle on top.  Similar to: circle is a fibre bundle over a point, the Mobius strip is a line bundle over the circle, but we don't have the cylinder as our fibre (or equivalently, total space) over the point.

Comment: @user10354138 Oh yes I got your point. The local trivilization of the circle bundle is given on a neighborhood of the total space of frame bundle, this does not necessarily covers the whole $SO(4)$ fiber for each point. That totally makes sense. Thanks for your patience!